# combine the table data in multiple csv files into one single csv file in ruby

Tags: java, ruby, ssis, etl

I have data coming from files which is spread in different files
like id,name,birthdate in one file and id,address in another file ie a csv files.
This is just an example the user has to specify the columns as its done while using SSIS 
and what i want to do is create the combined file which has the whole content as
id,name,birthdate,address

are there any tools available in java/ruby for this?
I have seen the sed solution but can not go with it as the columns are not fixed......
In short i want ET function from ETL ........

Answer (score 2):

Do you need Java or Ruby ? Instead have you looked at the Unix [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) utility ? It's analogous to the SQL `join` statement, except it works on text files.

Comment: Exactly! My reasoning behind using unix tools always is: If a simple and basic problem (like e.g. yours) can be solved with a unix tool, then you will hardly find any implementation in a higher language which is nearly as efficient and reliable. 40 years of constant tuning, bugfixing and optimizing DOES leave traces.

Comment: i want that functionality in the code ...meaning i want to embed the api of the toolin my program....if I go by "join" command in unix i will have to create a process and do that stuff....but i want a tool that will have some api for that...so that i can embed it in my application